# Program to count blanks, tabs, and newlines

Tags: c

I wrote the program as follows

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

double nl=0,nb=0,nt=0;
int c;

while((c=getchar())!=EOF) {
        if(c == '\n') nl++;
        if(c == ' ') nb++;
        if(c == '\t') nt++;
}

printf("lines = %f, blanks= %f, tabs=%f ",nl,nb,nt);
return 0;
```

}

Input:

```
h   a i
i   am krishna
```

Output:

```
lines = 1.000000, blanks= 8.000000, tabs=0.000000
```

In the input I gave two tabs(one in first line after `h`, and another in second line after `i`) and each tab contains 3 blank spaces in general. If we observe the output, it shows 1 new line(correct), 8 blanks(not correct, has to be 2) and 0 tabs (false, has to be 2).

Where it is going wrong? Why tab is counted as 3 spaces?

Comment: Why are you using `double` instead of an integer type

Comment: The output suggests you actually did put spaces and not tabs, maybe review your procedures

Comment: @M.M To deal with large input sizes

Comment: Probably because your tabs are already expanded to spaces in your input

Comment: I recommend to use `else if`

Comment: tabs are typically displayed as 4 or, more often, 8 spaces. 3 would be quite uncommon. given that, I don't see any tabs in your input

Comment: using `double` just means you get bogus results once the range gets to a certain point (which is less than UINT64_MAX)

Comment: Use `unsigned int`? On a system with 32-bit `int` then that should be enough for over four *billion* lines, spaces and tabs. If you are going to have more than that use `unsigned long long` which is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits. If you have bigger data than that, your program would have to run for hours and hours to process it, and I kind of doubt that will happen.

Comment: @Badda After commenting ` if(c == ' ') nb++;` also 0/p showing '0' tabs

Comment: Just use `size_t` for counting. It is guaranteed to hold the size of any valid object, so it should be enough for your inputs.

Comment: @FelixPalmen the input stream could be longer than `SIZE_MAX`, because it is not necessarily held in a single object at once

Comment: can't reproduce https://ideone.com/DL7odp.

Comment: @M.M it *could*, yes. In such a case, you probably know it and know how to deal with that ....

Comment: @Stargateur Your input is not the same as in OP

Comment: @hanugm What is your environment you're running this program on? And your compiler? Your OS?

Comment: @Badda That is the point.

Comment: @CoolGuy Compiler C(Gcc-4.9.2) - online compiler @ codechef..... https://www.codechef.com/ide

Comment: "In the input I gave two tabs"  [Apparently you didn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d34cdd5fad25996b)

Comment: Have no problem running your code on [ideone](https://ideone.com/2xYxG0) though. So whatever you're using is not considering the tab character correctly and replacing it with spaces. Or you are inputing it wrong.

Comment: Note that codechef seems to use fake tab. When you insert tab and move cursor with arrow keys, it looks like a tab. But when you click in the middle of the tab, it actually inserts cursor in the middle, revealing they are spaces.

Comment: The program is absolutely fine.

You cannot easily enter tabs in online applications. Don't ever count on being able to do that. If you want to test your program, install a compiler, or find an online one that does allow you to enter tabs.

Comment: Thanks. Codechef compiler gave wrong results...

Answer (score 2):

Your code works perfectly but the online compiler doesn't work properly because it uses spaces instead of tabs. Here is your code with little mods.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
/*Double has no sense*/
int nl=0,nb=0,nt=0;
int c;
while((c=getchar())!=EOF) {
        if(c == '\n') nl++;
        if(c == '\t') nt++;
        if(c == ' ') nb++;      
}

printf("lines = %d, blanks= %d, tabs=%d ",nl,nb,nt);
return 0;
}
```

Giving this input:

```
a   b c /*New line here*/
d   e f /*No new line*/
```

The output is correct:

```
lines = 1, blanks= 2, tabs=2
```

Comment: @user694733 I'm so sorry, I didn't see he used an online compiler.

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. uses a `switch()` statement rather than a string of `if()` statements (which means the integer is only evaluated once)
3. properly uses `double` literals rather than integer literals
4. follows the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

and now the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main( void )
{

    double nl=0.0;
    double nb=0.0;
    double nt=0.0;
    int c;

    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        switch(c)
        {
            case '\n':
               nl += 1.0;
               break;

            case ' ':
               nb += 1.0;
               break;

            case '\t':
               nt += 1.0;
               break;

            default:
               break;
        }
    }

    printf("lines = %f, blanks= %f, tabs=%f ",nl,nb,nt);
    return 0;
}
```

with the described input: 
(for illustrative purposes, `<tab>` actually is a tab character)

```
h<tab>a i
i<tab>am krishna
```

this is the output:

```
lines = 2.000000, blanks= 2.000000, tabs=2.000000
```